# In this particular example, how can I get the first record in each group?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In the code below, how can I get the first record in each group? My real query is more complex and I have to create the anonymous types, then use LoadDataRow on the dtResult table that I have created. I need to do this so I can use the CopyToDataTable functionality on my result:

```
           var results =
            (from cust in customers
             join invoice in invoices
             on
                 new
                 {
                     Prefix = cust.Field<string>("Prefix"),
                     CustNumb = cust.Field<int>("CustomerNumber")),
                     Suffix = cust.Field<int>("Suffix"))
                 }
             equals
                 new
                 {
                     Prefix = invoice.Field<string>("Prefix"),
                     CustNumb = invoice.Field<int>("CustomerNumber"),
                     Suffix = invoice.Field<int>("Suffix")
                 }
             group cust by new
             {
                 Prefix = cust["Prefix"],
                 CustomerNumber = cust["CustomerNumber"],
                 Suffix = cust["Suffix"],
                 Name = cust["Name"],
                 Address = cust["Address"]
             }
             into groups
             orderby groups.Key.Name
             // how do I get only the first record of each group?
             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(
                new object[]
                {
                    groups.Key.Prefix,
                    groups.Key.CustomerNumber,
                    groups.Key.Suffix,
                    groups.Key.Name,
                    groups.Key.Address
                }, false) 
             );
```

Comment: Just use `groups.First()`...

Comment: use groups.First() where?

Comment: In the query, where you want to get the first element of the group.

Comment: Where you need it. For instance, before `select` you could use `let first = groups.First()` and then inside the `select`, `first.Property1`, `first.Property2` etc.

Comment: trying "select groups.First() dtResult.LoadDataRow()..." doesn't work. I understand about the First() method of the group I just can't figure out how to make it work syntactically.

Comment: Ivan Stoev, your suggestion seems to work perfectly. Thank you so much! A very frustrating syntax thing that I simply couldn't resolve. Thanks again!